# Coef not defined because of similarity and pvalues

Tags: r, lm

I have a CRM data set used for an experiment, where the dummy W corresponds to the treatment/control group (see code below). When I tested for the independence of W from the other features, I realized two things:

- When using model.matrix, some coefficients (1 in this dummy dataset) were not defined because of similarity. This did not happen when feeding the DT straight to lm()
- The model obtained in both cases produces different results i.e., the p-values of the individual features changes

I (think that I) understand the concept of multi-collinearity but in this particular case I don't quite understand a) why it comes up b) why it has a different impact on model.matrix and lm

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

```
set.seed(1)

n = 302

DT = data.table(
    zipcode = factor(sample(seq(1,52), n, replace=TRUE)),
    gender = factor(sample(c("M","F"), n, replace=TRUE)),
    age = sample(seq(1,95), n, replace=TRUE),
    days_since_last_purchase = sample(seq(1,259), n, replace=TRUE),
    W = sample(c(0,1), n, replace=TRUE)
)

summary(DT)

m = model.matrix(W ~ . +0, DT)
f1 = lm(DT$W ~ m) 
f2= lm(W~ ., DT)

p_value_ratio <- function(lm)
{
    summary_randomization = summary(lm)
    p_values_randomization = summary_randomization$coefficients[, 4] 
    L = length(p_values_randomization)
    return(sum(p_values_randomization <= 0.05)/(L-1))
}

all.equal(p_value_ratio(f1), p_value_ratio(f2))

alias(f1)
alias(f2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `+ 0` in `model.matrix`. The second fit includes the intercept in the model matrix. If you exclude it, less factor levels (which are normally represented by the intercept) get excluded:

```
colnames(model.matrix(W ~ ., DT))
#excludes zipcode1 and genderf since these define the intercept

colnames(model.matrix(W ~ . + 0, DT))
#excludes only genderf
```

Note that `f1` includes an intercept, which is added by `lm` (I believe by an internal call to `model.matrix`, but haven't checked):

```
m = model.matrix(W ~ . + 0, DT);
f1 = lm(DT$W ~ m ); 
model.matrix(f1)
```

You might want this:

```
m = model.matrix(W ~ ., DT);
f1 = lm(DT$W ~ m[,-1]);
```

(Usually you construct the model matrix only manually if you want to use `lm.fit` directly.)

```
f2= lm(W~ ., DT);
all.equal(unname(coef(f1)), unname(coef(f2)))
#[1] TRUE
```

In the end, this boils down to your understanding of treatment contrasts. Usually, you shouldn't exclude the intercept from the model matrix.

Comment: Thanks Roland. I was reading this post https://www.r-bloggers.com/be-careful-with-using-model-design-in-r/ where the author points out that doing lm(0+...)  results in a different R^2 and F statistics. My read was that it should be avoided. Did I misunderstand that point?

Comment: @Stefano No, you didn't misunderstand. If that is a concern, you could use `f1 = lm(DT$W ~ m[,-1])`. What you *should*  do is simply use `f2`. If you want to go the manual route, better do it fully, i.e., use `lm.fit(m, DT[["W"]])` and calculate the statistics yourself.

Comment: Thanks! All clear! I'll have a look at lm.fit which I didn't know, and spend some time reading about the treatment contrasts as well.